# Retrieving one value from multiple input fields which have the same 'name' attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working with node and express and I have a form which is populated dynamically from the result of a query.

```
<% if (cars && cars.length > 0) { %>
<% cars.forEach(function(car) { %>
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-body text-capitalize">
        <div class="dropdown show">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle float-right" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit">Confirm Request</button>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/home">Cancel Request</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="number" name="car" value="<%= car.id %>" hidden /><strong><%= car.brand + ' ' + car.model %></strong>
    </div>
</div>
<% }) %>
<% } %>
```

As a result i will sometimes end up with just one input field with a name attribute of car and other times more than one input field but with the same name attribute of car like this

```
<input type="number" name="car" value="4" hidden="">
<input type="number" name="car" value="5" hidden="">
```

What I want to send only the value of the car which is selected when a user clicks the confirm request button. When i try to get the form values, i end up getting both values. This is the code I'm using to retrieve the form value

```
let car_id = req.body.car;
```

What will be the best way to get the value of only one these cars in this case?

Comment: `input` elements with the same name should not exist in the `number` type context, So I think the premise here is wrong. Same with `text`. This is what `radio` and `checkbox` types are meant for. Also, feel free to use a `select` list with the single name if possible.

Comment: In that case I will have to think my design through to achieve what i want